# Compare values of object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, compare

I have an object in JS like this:

```
var getToDoValue = document.getElementById("toDoInput").value;
var nameOfTeamMember = "Tobias";


var person = new Object();

person.task = "Task: " + getToDoValue;
person.member = "Member: " + nameOfTeamMember;
```

But problem comes when I try to enter the value of "nameOfTeamMember into an if statement:

```
var mem = person.member;

if (mem == "Tobias") {

    console.log("works");
  }
```

This does not work. But when I just console.log "var mem" outside of if statement it gives me "Member: Tobias". Any suggestions? Im still kinda new to JS so prob something with the comparisons

Comment: it should be: if (mem == 'Member: Tobias') as the value you have put in person.member is not just the name...you have put "Member: " + nameOfTeamMember;

Comment: Same result. I have tried that. However, I came up with a solution: I used .includes("Tobias"). Not sure what the diffrence is to be honest though. The other comparisons should work aswell.

Comment: of course that works because you can't expect 'Tobias' == 'Member: Tobias' to be true while 'Member: Tobias'.includes('Tobias') is true

Comment: When I used "Member: Tobias" == "Member: Tobias" is false for some reason.

Comment: can you post your whole code?

Answer (score -1):

the issue with you code is that the value in person.member is "Member: Tobias" as you pointed out from the result of your console.log, which is the result from the line of code below where you are concatenating the name with the string "Memeber: " and assigning it to the member property.

person.member = "Member: " + nameOfTeamMember;

One option you could use to do the comparison would be:

if (mem.contains("Tobias", 8) {

```
console.log("works");
```

}
The 8 is so your search starts after the colon (:) so you don't include "Member:" in it, just what comes after it, which is the actual member name.

Comment: there is no 'contains' method on strings...it is called includes and you don't need to specifiy a starting point